# WordPress keeps redirecting to an unsecure connection?

Tags: login, https

I'm trying to login to my site (clicked the Edit button) on secure connection and now it redirected to HTTP login page.

Why did this happen and how can I ***suggest*** (force) to WordPress to always use HTTPS?

Comment: To suggest or to force? In all the site or only in login/admin? (I would recommend to all site for SEO and many other reasons).

Comment: I'd like to enforce the login to be https at least and all the page views can be either. I can probably redirect my main site from http to https at my hosting company but the links to "Edit Page" are generated by WordPress. So they may continue to use HTTP links.

Comment: In the settings did you set the Wordpress Address and Site Address to https ?

Comment: I do not see that setting. I'm using WPMU. I just checked the Network Settings and the individual site settings and do not see the setting.

Comment: The solution to this is the same as on your other question. Check the [general settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen) on the network page.

Comment: By the way, having both URL versions available in the public site is seen as duplicated content. You should choose one version. I would recommend HTTPS version for login, admin and front end, either for guest and login in users..

Comment: OK thanks. So I need to update the SITE URL and Address. For individual sites it's in the settings page and for multisites I must enter enter it in the Network settings page (or manually in the wp config). @Burgi I think they took that setting out of the network page, here's a screen shot of what I see, https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For individual sites go to the settings page and update the SITE URL and Address.

For multisites / network installs I must enter enter it in the [Network Settings Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen) or if it's not there enter it manually in the `wp_config.php` page.

I'm also making sure that any one that enters http instead of https is redirected to the https version of the site. I can do this on the domain name / SSL settings page or in the .htaccess file in the root of the blog install.